# Can't access to sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 in Java 11

Tags: java, usb, token, pkcs#11

I try to write Java code to get the private key in my USB token
and I get the following error:

> return new SunPKCS11(tmpConfigFile.getAbsolutePath());

```
'SunPKCS11(sun.security.pkcs11.Config)' is not public in 'sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while when this question has been asked, but for all with the same question, this might still help.

Java 11 changed the way PKCS#11-keystores are accessed as described in the updated [PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.html#GUID-30E98B63-4910-40A1-A6DD-663EAF466991) for Java 11. Instead of initializing via constructor you're supposed to get the Provider via `Security.getProvider` and then call `configure`. An example can be found in the reference guide:

```
String configName = "/opt/bar/cfg/pkcs11.cfg";
Provider p = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
p = p.configure(configName);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways :

1. Create a new class that is in `sun.security.pkcs11` package, and create the object for you, like that:

```java
package sun.security.pkcs11;

public class MyClass {

   public static SunPKCS11 createPKCS(Config config) {
      return new SunPKCS11(config);
   }
}
```

2. Use [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html)

```java
public SunPKCS11 create(Config config) {
   Constructor<?> pkcsCons = SunPKCS11.class.getConstructor(Config.class);
   pkcs.setAccessible(true);
   return pkcsCons.newInstance(config);
}
```

3. Check [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) more speficially the 2.2 paragraph